# Download specific file in url using PHP/Python

Tags: php, python, web-crawler, wget

I previously used to use `wget -r` on the linux terminal for downloading files with certain extensions:

```
wget -r -A Ext URL
```

But now I was assigned by my lecturer to do the same thing using PHP or Python.  Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP function `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the contents of a documents. The first argument of the function is filename which can either be a local path to a file or a URL.
See example from PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess urllib pretty well for you

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve (URL, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/): Requests is the only Non-GMO HTTP library for Python, safe for human consumption.

Example (from the doc):

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python, use a web-crawler library such as scrapy.

It has [classes](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) that do all the work when passed arguments similar to those you put on the `wget` command line.

You can use scrapy [pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) to filter out unwanted downloads, and value-add the downloads such as adding thumbnails.